# saving FB comments in local database

Tags: php, facebook, comments

I am integrating FB Social Comments plugin on one of my website, however as I understand if I get so many comments on my articles and stuff, and later at some point for ANY reason FB blocks the url, all the comments will be gone and the whole lot of time and comments on articles will be wasted..

Is there anyway, I can get the posted comment with edge.create or anything else and store the comment in my local database ?

regards

Comment: You likely use the Graph API to do this, though I'm pretty sure saving the comments from facebook goes against the terms of use.

Comment: It's not really against TOS i think but it surely defeats the purpose of using comments... If you use facebook comments social pluggin and don't want to host them on facebook it probably cause you just didn't want to make your own commenting system and post to facebook on demand...

Comment: I concur with Mathieu, you should write your own "plugin" to do comments rather than try to "finagle" trying to capture them as they're posted by facebook's comments plugin.

Comment: I disagree with those opinions. FB would handle the spam issues better than you could. And the idea of a FB comment system is to tie real identity to the comments, to display friends' comments on the top, to rank them socially, etc. The system is more robust than a simple text editor. I would just run a Graph API call in the middle of the night to sync a backup of them.

Answer (score 0):

THANKS for the suggestions guys, as we all know the power of facebook traffic, it would have been great to use it, but now I have decided to have my own commenting system, but allow people to "Login" via facebook to post comments, soon as they do it will also post on their profile.. it way I will have all the comments in my local database..

thanks